# Upgraded to Gnome 3.4 on Debian, can't login to my main user?

Tags: debian, gnome

I get into this endless login-cycle if I attempt logging with my main user - I tried Gnome Classic and regular Gnome, but after I login it sends me back to the login.

The only way I can login is through another user.

This means that there's some hidden setting file in the home directory that messes things up.

How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it only happens for a specific user, examining this user's `~/.xsession-errors` could be useful.

Since you're using Debian, have a look at the files in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`, they're sourced by `Xsession` and thus give you an idea of what's happening when a new X11 session is started; e.g. `40x11-common_xsessionrc` is the place where `~/.xsessionrc` (i.e. `USERXSESSIONRC` set in `/etc/X11/Xsession`) is sourced.

Comment: Argh. `.gnomerc` had a commented out line which changed it to use xmonad, it had trouble parsing the comment delimiter and killing the entire line seemed to do it. Thanks.